# Qt: Reimplementing QAbstractItemView::dataChanged()

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I'd like to measure the time it takes to update a range of cells.  In Qt4.X I used to reimplement QAbstractItemView::dataChanged() to have a bit more control over how the view dealt with changes.  Now, I reimplement it but it seems to never get called.

```
void MyView::dataChanged( const QModelIndex& tl, const QModelIndex& br, const QVector<int>& roles )
{
    // do something
    QAbstractItemView::dataChanged( tl, br, roles );
    // do something else
}
```

I've got a std::cout in the above member function but it's never called.  Any ideas?

Comment: The model emits the signal just fine - paint() in the delegate is eventually called.  Just trying to take some times before and after paint() is called for each cell in the range.

Comment: You can track this time in delegate

Comment: That's within paint(), for only a single index, right?  I'm looking to time a range... Doing so within paint() would be cumbersome, and I dare say innacurate as the delegate doesn't know when the range is done.